# What is Ethan's power?

Tags: zeroes

In the series *Zeroes*, by Scott Westerfield, the protagonists and various other people have supernatural powers. Most of them are straightforward enough to understand, except Ethan's.

At first it seems like some kind of unconscious mind-reading that makes him more persuasive. Except later the voice claims that it is omniscient, and it doesn't seem to be totally bluffing, because at the end of the series he seems to consciously be aware, not only of what everyone on Earth is up to, but also of the future. His voice almost has an inverse relationship to crowds, too, compared to the others' powers.

What *is* his power, anyway? More specifically: Where does it come from? What caused it to change its behavior? What is its relationship to all the other powers, since his doesn't really seem to be dependent on the presence of people or devices?

Comment: https://zeroesbookseries.fandom.com/wiki/Scam

Comment: @Valorum - That is largely just the same things I said in the question, plus a few inaccuracies.